# Run meteor mobile project on android device [Windows 10]

Tags: android, meteor, mobile

So i'm working on meteor mobile project and when i try to run the app on my android device with `meteor run android-device` i get this Error :

> Error detecting IP address for mobile app to connect to: Found
>   multiple network interfaces with non-internal IPv4 addresses:
>   192.168.128.1, 192.168.177.1, 192.168.1.68 Please specify the address that the mobile app should connect to with --mobile-server.

Comment: Have you tried meteor run android device --mobile-server 198.xxx.xxx.x ? The Xs being one of the ip addressed above?

Comment: it's work thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device needs to be on the same wifi network as your machine. If that does not work then you need to enter in the suggested IPs as follows.

```
meteor run android-device --moible-server 192.xxx.xxx.x
```

Replace Xs with api config numbers of choice.